# How to numerically sort an external file with names and scores to get top five scores python

Tags: python, sorting

This is the code I have for this function so far:

```
def top_5_scores ():
   file = open('scores.txt','r')
   content = file.read()
   content.sort()
   print(content)
```

It comes up with an error saying:
`File "/home/scoring", line 4, in top_5_scores content.sort(). AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'sort'` .
In the external file it is set out as `username:score` and I need to sort the scores to print out the top five winners and their scores. Any ideas? Preferably as simple as possible (GCSE level code rather than professional)
Example of format of text file:

```
blue2:15   
gamer014:24   
louis123:9  
rlockwood:13
```

Thank you and sorry for the previous layout, I'm a bit new to this!

Comment: Where exactly do you even call `sort`?

Comment: Include the entire function definition, and the error message

Comment: The format of `scores.txt` is unclear, could you please include the top 10 lines or so from the file?